# Run python from python without Popen or os.system

Tags: python

I have a wrapper python script which repeatedly calls another python script via `os.system`. This works well enough, but there is quite a performance hit invoking the sub-shell and importing the modules again and again. How might I transform this to something more elegant and performant?

```
counter = 0
for thing in list_of_stuff:
    os.system("python inner_script.py %s result_%s" % (thing, counter)
    counter += 1
```

I would prefer to do this all in the wrapper, but can modify *inner-script.py* if that's the only or best way.

If it's relevant, the environment is Python 2.7 on Windows.

**edit:** I don't just import inner_script because it doesn't understand the command line parameters:

```
import inner_script    
counter = 0
for thing in ['TR2','TR5']:
    inner_script('%s result_%s' % (thing, counter))
counter += 1
```

result:

```
C:\> python xx-wrapper.py

inner_script [input features] [output workspace]
```

which is the usage message returned by inner_script.py:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print usage
    exit()

in_features = sys.argv[1]
out_folder  = sys.argv[2]

main(in_features, out_folder)
```

Comment: That really depends on the structure of `inner-script` ...

Comment: I must ask, why not just do `import inner-script.py` right off the bat?

Comment: Why don't you just import the other script?

Comment: also, look at `execfile`

Comment: @Torxed, JBernardo I added what happens when I use import

Comment: @mgilson I added the relevant part of inner_script, at least I think it's the relevant part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `inner-script.py` create a class around the task that the script does.

```
for thing in list_of_stuff:
    x = __import__('inner-script')
    x.className(thing, counter)
```

This should be efficient enough.

---

Or, if you can't/wont modify the inner-script.py, here's a way to call it from within python and pass variables as local() or global() variables which the script can read from.. just as if you passed the params upon execution in your example:

```
x = __import__('inner-script', globals(), (thing, counter), [], -1)
```

Then whatever stuff you want to be, [more info can be found here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Comment: can this populate inner_script's `sys.argv` parameters?

Comment: `sys.argv` is passed down to all imported modules, so whatever parameters exists in `sys.argv` in the main code will be passed down to `__import__('inner-script',...)`, you can add stuff to sys.argv before importing, that would give you a way to populate `sys.argv` in `inner_script.py`

Comment: @mattwilkie `sys.argv.append('WhamBamThankYouMam')` :)

Comment: thanks! that is enough to get me by, though I initially tripped over the fact that arguments passed to wrapper.py will prefix and extend what inner_script.py sees as sys.argv (the index numbers are shifted so inner_script uses the wrong ones). So this answer achieves what I asked for, while J.F. Sebastian's is better form for the long term.

Comment: actually, the `__import__` only works on the first round of the loop, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Wrong, add a `reload(x)` and you're fine.. especially if you've structured the script to use a class for it's operation, that way you can do `reload(x)` and then `x.className()`

Comment: It's because per design, Python is built to handle duplicate imports and simply use a shared address space for the module you're importing (this is great for log-modules and config-modules) but can cause unwanted affects, such as in your case (not sure why you would want to import the same script over and over tho.. just add a class, initate a new instance of that class each run isntead).

Comment: ah, I didn't know about reload. With that I have something that appears to work for the "don't modify inner_script" scenario. As for why not a class -- I'm not an evolved enough snake charmer to have any. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to be able to write:

```
from inner_module import some_function

for counter, thing in enumerate(list_of_stuff):
    some_function(thing, counter)
```

To achieve it, move the processing code from inner-script to a separate function. You could put it in a new module or rename the script and leave the function there. For example, `inner-script.py`:

```
import sys
# tons of other imports..

# parse args
thing, counter = sys.argv[1:]

# do something..
print thing, counter
```

Can be converted to `inner_module.py`:

```
import sys
# tons of other imports..

def some_function(thing, counter):
    print thing, counter

def main():
    # parse args
    thing, counter = sys.argv[1:]

    # do something..
    some_function(thing, counter)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Torxed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779052/14420) and accompanying commentary, I have something that appears to work for the "don't modify inner_script" scenario. Although the initial goal has been accomplished, in the process of building it has become clear to me that the best thing to do is recast `inner-script` into `inner_script` module, after [J.F. Sebastian's template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779353/14420). There are just too many things that might or might not work right with this, however, it *is* an answer, so I leave it for anyone else who might need it:

```
counter = 0
for thing in ['1st','2nd', '3rd']:
    output = '%s_%s' % (thing, counter)
    sys.argv.insert(1, thing)
    sys.argv.insert(2, output)

    if counter == 0:
        x = __import__('inner_script', sys.argv)
    else:
        reload(x)

    del sys.argv[2] # in reverse order so as not to change index #'s before done
    del sys.argv[1] 
    counter += 1
```

Results:

```
Processing 1st into 1st_0
Processing 2nd into 2nd_1
Processing 3rd into 3rd_2
```